# Simplifying $1 - 3\sin x \cos x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I have
$$0 = 1 - 3 \sin x \cos x$$

I changed it to:

$$2\sin x \cos x + \sin x \cos x = 1$$
$$\sin 2x + \sin x \cos x = 1$$

How do I simplify this further and get it in terms of one trig function?

Comment: Use $\sin x\cos x = \frac{1}{2}2\sin x\cos x = \frac{1}{2}\sin (2x)$.

Answer (score 1):

You could use $\sin(2x)=2\sin(x)\cos(x)$

Comment: But that would give me $3sinxcosx = 1$ and I wouldn't know how to get it into one function